# How do charities measure donated CPU usage?

Tags: performance, cpu, performance-testing, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture

I've seen from other questions how to measure your own CPU usage. But how does this happen in a distributed way? E.g. what if millions of computers around the world all donate CPU power to (say) cancer research. I've seen this a lot: often there is a kind of prestige league table about who has donated the most CPU power. For example, on the Chess engine Stockfish tests: http://tests.stockfishchess.org/tests

How is this actually measured? In particular, is it easy for someone to spoof how much CPU power they actually donated?

Thanks for the help!

Lue

Comment: Peters answer is good but some of these leaderboards might simply rely on self reporting. This is easily spoofed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually they measure amount of work contributed, in terms of the problem being solved.  Not just CPU hours.

Sometimes the system includes checks to verify that an answer was correct, and not just random garbage; depending on the specific problem this can be done in different ways.  e.g. accumulate some checksum of internal temporary results that you can only get if you've done the work.  Then send the same work units out to multiple clients and check for mismatches; if you find any you know someone's cheating or has bad hardware that's polluting the results.